# What will be the output of the following code in VBA?

Tags: vb.net, vba

This question been asked in last year exams. I don't think it will gonna give output due to `<>` this statement. What's your thoughts?

```
Dim sum As Integer, k As Integer
sum = 0
k = 5
Do While k <> 0
    sum = sum + k * k
    MsgBox "sum" & sum
    k = k - 1
Loop
```

Comment: That loops from k=5 to k=1.  What is the issue with `<>` ?

Comment: Did you even TRY running it to see what it did?

Comment: [Open letter to Students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP only has to try to run the code to get the answer. No effort put into the question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will give output of `55`. It will loop from `k=5` to `k=1` and `sum` will be incremented with the result of `k*k` in each loop:

```
sum = 0  + 5 * 5 = 25
sum = 25 + 4 * 4 = 41
sum = 41 + 3 * 3 = 50
sum = 50 + 2 * 2 = 54
sum = 54 + 1 * 1 = 55
```

To be precise, there will be no output at all, but there will be five popup messages reading:

```
sum25
sum41
sum50
sum54
sum55
```

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sum As Integer, k As Integer
    sum = 0
    k = 5
    Do While k <> 0
        sum = sum + k * k
        Debug.Print "K" & k & " - " & "sum" & sum
        k = k - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
K5 - sum25
K4 - sum41
K3 - sum50
K2 - sum54
K1 - sum55
```

Shown in Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

The output will be your program will be

```
sum25
sum41
sum50
sum54
sum55
```